# I have created gallery metabox but it does not work

Tags: wordpress

here is the code which I got from github page:

```
define('MY_POST_TYPE', 'my');
  define('MY_POST_SLUG', 'gallery');
  function my_register_post_type () {
    $args = array (
        'label' => 'Gallery',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'excerpt' ),
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'my_meta_box_cb',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true
    );
    register_post_type( MY_POST_TYPE , $args );
  }
  add_action( 'init', 'my_register_post_type' );
  function my_meta_box_cb () {
    add_meta_box( MY_POST_TYPE . '_details' , 'Media Library', 'my_meta_box_details', MY_POST_TYPE, 'normal', 'high' );
  }
  function my_meta_box_details () {
    global $post;
    $post_ID = $post->ID; // global used by get_upload_iframe_src
    printf( "<iframe frameborder='0' src=' %s ' style='width: 100%%; height: 400px;'> </iframe>", get_upload_iframe_src('media') );
  }
```

It shows my gallery page and media up-loader section on that page nicely, but there is no insert into post button inside that uploader and I am unable to insert image to that post. Additionally, If I upload image from my computer it has insert into post button, once I click upon that button page all my media up-loader screen disappears and nothing happens ? what's wrong with my code or approach please

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `editor` in your supports:

```
define('MY_POST_TYPE', 'my');
define('MY_POST_SLUG', 'gallery');
function my_register_post_type () {
    $args = array (
        'label' => 'Gallery',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'excerpt', 'editor' ),
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'my_meta_box_cb',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true
        );
    register_post_type( MY_POST_TYPE , $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_register_post_type' );
function my_meta_box_cb () {
    add_meta_box( MY_POST_TYPE . '_details' , 'Media Library', 'my_meta_box_details', MY_POST_TYPE, 'normal', 'high' );
}

function my_meta_box_details () {
    global $post;
$post_ID = $post->ID; // global used by get_upload_iframe_src
printf( "<iframe frameborder='0' src=' %s ' style='width: 100%%; height: 400px;'> </iframe>", get_upload_iframe_src('media') );
}
```

Once you add the editor, when you click 'Insert into post' you can see the inserted link in the editor. Which is presumably what you need.

There is a problem with disappearing metabox when you do upload the image.

In my opinion, you don't really need the extra uploader in a metabox. You have 'Add Media' Button above the editor - you can add images, videos or galleries in your CPT that way.

**EDIT**

You could ditch the media uploader and just call the default `wp.media` like this:

```
function my_meta_box_details () {
    global $post;
    // Here we get the current images ids of the gallery
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $my_gallery = (isset($custom["my_gallery"][0])) ? $custom["my_gallery"][0] : '';

    // We display the gallery
    ?>
    <style>
        .gallery-item{
            width:150px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .gallery-item img{
            width: 150px;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="gallery_images">
        <?php
        $img_array = (isset($my_gallery) && $my_gallery != '') ? explode(',', $my_gallery) : '';
        if ($img_array != '') {
            foreach ($img_array as $img) {
                echo '<div class="gallery-item">'.wp_get_attachment_image($img).'</div>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <p class="separator">
        <input id="my_gallery_input" type="hidden" name="my_gallery" value="<?php echo $my_gallery; ?>" data-urls=""/>
        <input id="manage_gallery" title="Manage gallery" type="button" value="Manage gallery" />
        <input id="empty_gallery" title="Empty gallery" type="button" value="Empty gallery" />
    </p>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(document).on('click', '#manage_gallery', upload_gallery_button);

        function upload_gallery_button(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $input_field = $('#my_gallery_input');
            var ids = $input_field.val();
            var gallerysc = '[gallery ids="' + ids + '"]';
            wp.media.gallery.edit(gallerysc).on('update', function(g) {
                var id_array = [];
                var url_array = [];
                $.each(g.models, function(id, img){
                    url_array.push(img.attributes.url);
                    id_array.push(img.id);
                });
                var ids = id_array.join(",");
                ids = ids.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
                var urls = url_array.join(",");
                urls = urls.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
                $input_field.val(ids);
                var html = '';
                for(var i = 0 ; i < url_array.length; i++){
                    html += '<div class="gallery-item"><img src="'+url_array[i]+'"></div>';
                }

                $('.gallery_images').html('').append(html);
            });

        }

        $(document).on('click', '#empty_gallery', empty_gallery_button);

        function empty_gallery_button(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $input_field = $('#my_gallery_input');
            $input_field.val('');
            $('.gallery_images').html('');
        }
    });
    </script>
    <?php

}

function my_metabox_save(){
    global $post;
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    } elseif(is_object($post)){
        $my_gallery = (isset($_POST['my_gallery'])) ? $_POST['my_gallery'] : '';
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_gallery', $my_gallery);
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'my_metabox_save');
```

And remove the `editor` from your `supports` argument. Should be working fine.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want editor at all ... i just want when ever I click on the insert to post button, it should add image below or top of the media uploader ... in this way client will be able to see how many and which images he/she has selected and I can use those images as well ... Kindly guide me the solution how to achieve this with my above code or any thing else I needed ??? Thanks for that in advance

Comment: I have added the editor and it adds image to editor, but still that uploder disappers, additionally I don't want that image in the editor and no editor at all ... How, can I get those images like gallery and can use those images like in gallery or slider etc ... ???